# fitting model when using cross validation to evaluate performance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm currently trying to compare multiple models. 
I made a script that evaluates the performance using 10 fold cross validation to get the most realistic performance. 
My question is, does it matter what training and test data it is fitted to? e.g. should i find the training and test set that gave the best performance and fit the model again after

```
CV = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=K, shuffle=True)
# Split data

for train_index, test_index in CV.split(X, y):

    for model in models:

        # splitting up data set
        X_train = X.iloc[train_index]
        y_train = y.iloc[train_index]
        X_test = X.iloc[test_index]
        y_test = y.iloc[test_index]

        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        print(model.score(X_test, y_test) * 100)
```

Comment: The `model` variable will always be the most recent one fitted, with that fit. So inside the double loop, you should be fine for the evaluation, but once outside the loop, you have to select and refit your model again to make sure you have the correct model and fit.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have a problem with the correct model selection. It is only the fit. Does it matte what training and test data it is fitted to? e.g. should i find the training and test set that gave the best performance and fit the model again after?

Comment: Yes, it matters. But you should (also) update your question, but your actual question is currently asked in a comment. The question itself, to me, asks something different.

Comment: After a CV, we normally fit to the *whole* training set - we don't select the CV fold data which had the best performance...

Comment: Thank you both! 
desertnaut- I know this might be a bit off original question but then what if I want to reevaluate the performance later. This could be after I have tuned the model. Then I have already fitted my model to the whole training data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that this question is much better for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange community to answer (and there are plenty of [posts on cross validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-validation)).

However, since you asked it on Stack Overflow...
As user 9769953 commented: it does matter.

To my mind cross-validation has two main uses:

1. Checking if the data is significantly different in one folds to skew the training of the model.
2. Verifying the performance on the unseen data (the left-out fold).

The expected result is that you are going to have different results (the same result for each fold should make you suspicious about the data or the model training process).

The performance of cross validation makes only sense as an average over all of the folds' results. This is a more realistic value for performance comparing to the "1-fold validation" (i. e. running the model on the data it was learning from) as typically you are going to be running the model on data that the model have not seen.

Comment: Thank you! that makes sense to use the mean instead of the median.